# How do I setup FsUnit with Mono on Linux?

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fsunit

Without Visual Studio, I can't use NuGet. How can I setup a project to use FsUnit manually?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of NuGet works fine on Mono. Just call `Mono NuGet.exe` with the needed command line